# How can we get Block Bundle Type for block in code?

Tags: 8, blocks

I am trying to override block content by using [hook_preprocess_block(&$variables)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/8.2.x). I was expecting to find bundle type in `$variable`, but not getting anything related to this.

Here is kint display of $variable inside the function - [image]

More Info - This is a block type (say `content_slider`) created from Drupal UI & a block (say `content_slider_homepage`) is added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UUID from the custom block is in the variable `derivative_plugin_id`. You can use this UUID to load the block and get the bundle:

```
$block = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('block_content', $uuid);

if ($block) {
  $block_type = $block->bundle();
}
```

Or look in `$variables['elements']`. Here you'll find the custom block entity loaded in the variables and probably the block type as well. You can also use `hook_block_content_view()` if this is for a module. See the comments from @Berdir.

Comment: there is no preprocess_block_content because there is no block_content template, but there is hook_block_content_view() and .. view_alter() and you can get it in preprocess_block() too

Comment: Specifically, what you are looking for is in elements, so dump that key to see its content

Answer (score 7):

This is how I would do it:

```
use \Drupal\block_content\BlockContentInterface;


/**
 * Implements HOOK_preprocess_block().
 *
 * @param $variables
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $content = $variables['elements']['content'];
  if (isset($content['#block_content']) && $content['#block_content'] instanceof BlockContentInterface) {

    if ($content['#block_content']->bundle() == 'xxx') {
      // ...
    }

  }
}
```